# Using JSON_EXTRACT in WHERE clause using Laminas-Db

Tags: zend-framework3, laminas

I have a mysql table with a json datatype used to store json_encoded data:

```
id|author_id|date_inserted|comments
---------------------------------------------
1|32|2022-04-01|{"id": "343","some":"data"}
2|15|2022-02-15|{"id": "24","some":"data"}
3|24|2022-05-22|{"id": "995","some":"data"}
```

Using laminas-db, how is it possible to use JSON_EXTRACT in a where clause? For instance, when using a tablegateway, i would like to update the json data of a row using something like the following:

```
$this->tableGateway->update($data, [JSON_EXTRACT('comments', '$.id') = 24]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve it with the following:

```
 $commentId = 24;
 $where = new Where();
 $where->addPredicate(new Expression('JSON_EXTRACT(comments, "$.id") = ?', $commentId));
 return $this->tableGateway->update($data, $where);
```